# Why does spell check not work if the figure has a label?

Tags: texmaker, editors

In Texmaker, in the `caption` environment, why does spell check not work if the `figure` has a label?

This is an example I made to show this 'feature':

[image]

From the first line, we see that the spell-checker is working as normal. This also follows in the `figure` environment, but *not* in the `caption` environment.

I tried playing around with it to see what exactly caused it... turns out it's the presence of a `label`. We see from the second `caption` that the spell-check is performed correctly.

Comment: Note: I have retagged the question to reflect that the question is not about any topic related to TeX itself but about an editor in particular.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me (I have used, but not played around that much with Texmaker, nor do I have access to it now).

Comment: What happens if you put the label in the next line?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel That actually fixes the problem, for whatever reason.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Any reason that should happen (is it bad LaTeX syntax?) or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a bug (or at least an annoyance) in the editor and has nothing to do with (La)TeX. The syntax is correct. You may file a bug report under on [Texmaker’s bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list).

I assume that a regular expression is used to grab the `\caption` text that follow some tight rule. As long as `\caption`’s argument is not closed the spell checking is active.

I suggest to write the `\label` on its own line until this is fixed.

[image]

Comment: The space between `}` and `\label` does not have an effect. But maybe the algorithm for syntax highlighting (notice that `{fig:FigureName}` is different once with and once without the final `}`) messes with the spell checker.